# Cannot open database "Auth" requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user 'ServerName'

Tags: sql-server, iis, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I am developing an application in .net Core 2.1, where I apply the authentication by aspnet identity users. The database is on a server and my program in .net core is on another server with IIS. My program works correctly locally but when I deploy it to my server and try to access one of my methods to perform the login I get the following error:

> Can not open database "Auth" requested by the login. The login failed.Login failed for user '[NAME-OF-SERVER-WITH-IIS]'.

The weird thing is that in my connection string I specified that the user that I was connecting to would be "sa".

**Startup.cs - ConfigureServices method**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        String con = "Data Source=<Servername>;Initial Catalog=Auth;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=<Password>;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(con,
          b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Auth")));
    ...
    }
```

**AuthController.cs - Login method**

```
[HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]CredentialsViewModel credentials)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            var identity = await GetClaimsIdentity(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password);

            if (identity == null)
                return BadRequest(Errors.AddErrorToModelState("login_failure", "Invalid username or password.", ModelState));

            var jwt = await Tokens.GenerateJwt(identity, jwtFactory, credentials.UserName, jwtOptions, new JsonSerializerSettings { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
            return new OkObjectResult(jwt);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not a C# developer, but i'm pretty sure you're mixing SQL Server Login Authentication and Integrated Security there. You can't pass a SQL login and Password, **AND** use `Trusted_Connection=True`. A SQL Server Authentication login doesn't use a trusted connection.

Comment: Larnu is correct. You either pass the SQL Login credentials or you have the App pool authenticated as a domain account and use trusted connection

Comment: On a related note, it's an awful idea for an application to make use of an `sysadmin` account, Create a separate login and give the login **only** the permissions it needs.

Comment: That's correct Larun. This solved the problem my it was just my mistake with the connection string. If you want you can post it to mark it as solved.